# Find the value and delete the whole object associated with that array from a deeply nested array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, underscore.js, lodash

I browsed So many questions to find out logics for finding Index in a deeply nested array of object, I didn't find it useful for my requirement though.

in search of Solution in **Javascript, Lodash/Underscore** would be Fine too.
Let me just phrase out the Whole requirement, Hoping I get a path to find the solution for this issue.

Requirement:
I have an array of objects

```
arrObj =[
        {
            "id":3208,
            "name":"List",
            "issueResponses":[

            ],
            "isActive":false
        },
        {
            "id":3209,
            "name":"Me",
            "issueResponses":[
            ],
            "isActive":false
        },
        {
            "id":3314,
            "name":"SNew",
            "issueResponses":[

            ],
            "isActive":false
        },
        {
            "id":3315,
            "name":"Olive",
            "issueResponses":[
                {
                    "id":3282,
                    "name":"related to Olive",
                    "issueResponses":[

                    ],
                    "isActive":false
                },
                {
                    "id":3316,
                    "name":"My olives are not yet picked",
                    "issueResponses":[
                        {
                            "id":3317,
                            "name":"Pickup Not Done",
                            "issueResponses":[

                            ],
                            "isActive":false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

As we can see its deeply nested, I have another array

**delValue = [3317,3282]**, And tomorrow it might be anything in these Deep Nesting. 
I have to find these delValue arrays in arrObj and delete all those Objects which has "id" as these Values.

I am trying to solve this in a generic way which can support any number deep search Level and Deletion of the Object from that.

Please help me out in this, if More Information needed will be happy to provide.

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter to achieve this:

```
function removeDeletions(array, deletion) {
    return array.filter(el => {
        if (Array.isArray(el.issueResponses)) el.issueResponses = removeDeletions(el.issueResponses, deletion);
        return ! deletion.includes(el.id);
    })
}
```

DEMO:

```js
let arrObj = [{
    "id": 3208,
    "name": "List",
    "issueResponses": [

    ],
    "isActive": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3209,
    "name": "Me",
    "issueResponses": [],
    "isActive": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3314,
    "name": "SNew",
    "issueResponses": [

    ],
    "isActive": false
  },
  {
    "id": 3315,
    "name": "Olive",
    "issueResponses": [{
        "id": 3282,
        "name": "related to Olive",
        "issueResponses": [

        ],
        "isActive": false
      },
      {
        "id": 3316,
        "name": "My olives are not yet picked",
        "issueResponses": [{
          "id": 3317,
          "name": "Pickup Not Done",
          "issueResponses": [

          ],
          "isActive": false
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
]
let delValue = [3317, 3282];

function removeDeletions(array, deletion) {
  return array.filter(el => {
    if (Array.isArray(el.issueResponses)) el.issueResponses = removeDeletions(el.issueResponses, deletion);
    return !deletion.includes(el.id);
  })
}

console.log(removeDeletions(arrObj, delValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep checking `issueResponses` - like so:

```
function deleteIssueResponses(issues, ids) {
    for (let i = issues.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (issues[i].issueResponses.length) {
            deleteIssueResponses(issues[i].issueResponses, ids);
        }

        if (ids.contains(issues[i].id)) {
            issues.splice(i, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

And call it:

```
deleteIssueResponses(arrObj, [3317,3282]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be quite simple to solve with some recursion. This function will delete the given ids in the array passed to it, or else call itself to do the same for the nested arrays.

```
function deleteIds(arr, ids) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (ids.indexOf(arr[i].id) !== -1) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      i--;
    } else {
      deleteIds(arr[i].issueResponses, ids);
    }
  }
}
```

Call with `deleteIds(arrObj, delValue)` as in your question.

Answer (score 0):

We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for basic data processing tasks like this. Once you wrap your head around how to use it, it's pretty good and powerful. Here is how you could answer your questions:

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const prune = (values, data) => objectScan(['**[*].id'], {
  rtn: 'count',
  filterFn: ({ gparent, gproperty, value }) => {
    if (values.includes(value)) {
      gparent.splice(gproperty, 1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(data);

const arrObj = [{ id: 3208, name: 'List', issueResponses: [], isActive: false }, { id: 3209, name: 'Me', issueResponses: [], isActive: false }, { id: 3314, name: 'SNew', issueResponses: [], isActive: false }, { id: 3315, name: 'Olive', issueResponses: [{ id: 3282, name: 'related to Olive', issueResponses: [], isActive: false }, { id: 3316, name: 'My olives are not yet picked', issueResponses: [{ id: 3317, name: 'Pickup Not Done', issueResponses: [], isActive: false }] }] }];

console.log(prune([3317, 3282], arrObj)); // return number of deletes
// => 2

console.log(arrObj);
// => [ { id: 3208, name: 'List', issueResponses: [], isActive: false }, { id: 3209, name: 'Me', issueResponses: [], isActive: false }, { id: 3314, name: 'SNew', issueResponses: [], isActive: false }, { id: 3315, name: 'Olive', issueResponses: [ { id: 3316, name: 'My olives are not yet picked', issueResponses: [] } ] } ]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@15.0.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)